# THREE.js custom tangent attribute how do i load it

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm looking at this example:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_custom_attributes.html

and notice that the custom displacement attribute gets filled by vertices.length

```
for ( var v = 0; v < vertices.length; v++ ) {
    values[ v ] = 0;
    noise[ v ] = Math.random() * 5;
    }
```

My question is, how does this relate to the number of normals, uvs and tangents?

When i export my model from 3ds max, i have more UVs than vertices. I need to assign tangents per this UV number because they are different at seams. I can't export a mesh that has double vertices at seams but while still keeping the averaged normals. But i have been able to export tangents and bitangents as another JSON model (i export them as vertex pos).

How exactly does all of this work, because i assume, even though that there are less vertices than UVs, the GPU actually breaks this apart and doubles the vertices at every UV seam, but i have no idea how to map all of this in the attribute buffer.

**updated**

I wrote a little exporter for max, basically mimicking the JSON structure:

```
"vertices": [floats],
"vertices_count": 486,
"uvs": [[floats]],
"uv_count": 364,
"PH_normal":[floats],
"PH_normal_count": 546,
"PH_tangent":[floats],
"PH_tangent_count": 546,
"PH_binormal":[floats],
"PH_binormals_count": 546,
"faces":[integers, actually the 42 structure from the json, i did it for comparison],
"PH_customIndex":[integers, this is how i mapped the values from exported normals,tangents and binormals to face3],
"PH_customIndexNum":960,
"PH_UVindex":[integers, this is how i mapped the values |faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 0 ]| from the exported uvs above],
"PH_UVindexNum":960,
"PH_FaceIndex":[integers, this is how i mapped the faces to vertices],
"PH_FaceIndexNum":960
```

My .geometry.faces[0] has an additional array called vertexBinormals in addition to vertexTangents and vertexNormals.

Essentially, i don't understand how to map these vertexBinormals values to an attribute and map it according to the rest. I was able to succeed in rendering what i wanted by copying the code for the tangent buffer (although i resized it to hold 3 values);

**update2***

This actually seems to work fine (will post something live).

But the question would be, in case of the above export results, using:

```
var attributes= {
    bitangents: {
        type: 'v3',
        value: []
    }
};
```

The model has 320 faces, 162 vertices, and 182 uvs, normals, tangents and binormals. How should i fill this array in order to just give it to a shaderMaterial?

**update**
   initWebGLObjects()
       geometry.geometryGroupsList[A].faces3[]

gives a "faces3" array of 320 in the case above, 
then further down

```
if (Ha.tangentsNeedUpdate && Ha.hasTangents) {
    //loops through things and fills 
    j.bindBuffer(j.ARRAY_BUFFER, w.__webglTangentBuffer);
```

this buffer gets written in 3,840 times, 3 times per face 4 values each time.
i filled another one in the same manner only using 3 values, and this seemed to have worked, the tangent normal map maps 1:1 to what i exported.

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand your post. Can you show a simple live example and ask a specific question about it? Also, to help you clarify your question, search for "boundTo" in `WebGLRenderer.js` and study http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_wireframe.html. (Note: In `WebGLRenderer`, geometry is broken into chunks with one material per chunk. As you read, just assume 'chunk' is the geometry.) Finally, `tangents` are a property of `Face3`, and are not usually passed as a custom attribute. They are also of length 4, not 3.

Comment: Hi West, thanks for the commment. I have this to show as an example, but the code is really messy since i'm pretty new to this. 

Essentially the gui will allow you to turn off the normal map and show the normals. If you zoom in on the hubcap youll see that it consists of many chunks. 

I have a problem with my workflow: and i can't generate the tangents if i override the normal, (welding two normals on a seam while keeping two vertices).

Comment: Ouch the five minute edit thing went out.

The link is here http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/new/camry/camry_wheel_test_v3.html. So the problem is, if i have all the verts welded, (all smooth mesh) i cant match the tangents with verts in three.js (i dont understand what happens with the discrepancy in vert number). If i break the mesh into chunks at uv seams, this mostly does work, but sometimes i want to use an all smooth mesh and i cant override the normals - i would like to be able to weld the normals while leaving verts duplicated, but i'm not there yet.

Comment: Here is another example, http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/new/mesh_test/index_normal_final.html
There are some seams that i might solve by adding more padding, but having being able to generate all of this a bit different could help even more. 

I'm not too sure how all of this works. What happens with a vert that has two uv values (or more) instead of one.

Comment: You are not making it very easy for someone to help you, quite frankly.   From the looks of it, you are quite experienced, and you will just have to study the three.js data structures and examples. See `Geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ]`. The whole issue of marrying the content-creation pipeline and the three.js-rendering pipeline has been a difficult one -- particularly addressing the tangents issues. Consider using `MeshPhongMaterial`, which uses derivative tangents, and does not require explicit "attribute" tangents.

Comment: I am far from experienced with this :), i only started learning javascript back in october, and my webgl/opengl knowledge is limited mostly to theory, but im persistent and have covered a lot of ground.

I am persistent though :) and i did cover a lot of ground.

I wrote an exporter, (updated in post). I dug deeper into the webgl part of three.js and was able to introduce a new buffer to hold these attributes. I basically duplicated the code everywhere i found mention of __webglTangentBuffer. It works great, but it broke everything that is not imported by my importer. Thanks for the patience!

Comment: Added some more updates

Comment: You have to make it easy for someone to help you. Start over with a new post. Refer to your simple, live example, and ask a specific question about it.